Terragrunt not finding .tf files for use in folder
Hi I am getting an error as per below:
ERRO[0000] Did not find any Terraform files (*.tf) in /Users/nb1776/Desktop/Misc Code/Terraform_Terragrunt_Example_structure/Terraform/services/cloud_sql_server/dev
My folder set up is as follows -
terraform /
|--- terragrunt.hcl
|--- services /
|------ cloud_sql /
|--------- dev /
|--------- terragrunt.hcl
|--------- test /
|--------- prod /
|--------- module /
|--------- main.tf
|--------- variables.tf

In my top level .hcl file I have this.
# terraform/terragrunt.hcl
remote_state {
  backend = "gcs"
  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  config = {
    project  = "project_id"
    location = ""
    bucket   = ""
    prefix   = "terraform/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"

    gcs_bucket_labels = {
      owner = "terragrunt_sa"
      name  = "terraform_state_storage"
    }
  }
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite"
  contents  = <<EOF
provider "google" {
  version = "~> 3.16.0"

  credentials = "${local.env.credentials_path}"
  project     = "${local.env.project}"
  region      = "${local.env.region}"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = "${local.env.credentials_path}"
  project     = "${local.env.project}"
  region      = "${local.env.region}"
}
  EOF
}


In my dev level .hcl file I have
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

terraform {
  source = "../modules"
}

inputs = {
    project_id = ""
    name   = "test"
    pwd = "test123"
    region = ""
    zone   = "b"
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    enable_backups = false
}

The error is quite generic so I'm not sure why the .tf files in the modules folder aren't being recognized/found? Has anyone encountered this?
I attempted terragrunt plan in the dev folder and I expected it to show the plan for the sql resource with the inputs from the terragrunt file in dev.

This sounds like it's to do with the the fact your using relative paths. You specify the source as "../modules" but your not taking into account how terragrunt runs and renders and does relative references. Have a look at https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#get_terragrunt_dir. It should help you understand you need to tell terragrunt how to find the modules dir relative to where the terragrunt.hcl file lives
